# Add data to the old tab of JTabbedpane in java for it to work

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I am developing an application that needs to use JTabbedpane, when I add a new tab and I want to add data to the Jtable in the old tab, it does not show the newly added data, but when I select the newly created tab and add it, it still display the newly added data. Does anyone know a way so that when I select the old tab and add data it works fine

I can select random tab to add data to jatable and it shows the newly added data

Comment: If you want to add data to a table, then you need a reference to the table. We have no idea how each tab references the table in the first tab. I would guess you just need to make sure you define the table as an instance variable in your class so all tabs can reference the table. If you need more help, then post a [mre].

Comment: no, i mean when i create a new tab it will be a new table, this new table and the old one in the old tab are 2 different tables and when I select the old tab and add data, the table in the old tab will pick up and display

Comment: As I said you need a reference to the table. You need to access the table on the current tab. We have no idea how your code is structured so we can't give an exact solution. It is up to you to make sure you can reference the table on each tab.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.